# get touchstart event to bubble up from d3 zoom to the svg

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am using the d3 zoom behaviour on my svg element and i also have a dblclick event of the svg element.

Under desktop i can zoom with mouse wheel and double click as needed. However when i go to an ipad the double click does not go through.

So i have added a touchstart listener to handle a double tap on the svg (the svg also has the zoom behaviour associated with it)

The trouble i am getting is that the zoom appears to grab the touch start and then the underlining svg touchstart event does not go through so i cannot do my double tap.

Is there a way to keep the touchstart in the zoom, as it is needed for the paning and pinch zooming i believe, as if i do .on('touchstart.zoom',null) panning does not work and pinch zoom does not work either. But allow me to bubble it up so i can do my double tap functionality.

Cheers
Mark

**UPDATE- Looking into this a bit more the W3C standard dictate that this is the way it should work and touch events are to be stopped from bubbling up**

Comment: Same struggle here.  Can't find an answer for this anywhere.

Comment: Look at my update section. That was the solution it is just something that is not supported.

Comment: To add to that I just had to think of a way around it by not using the touch event if I recall. I will look when u get into work and update on here.